# How do I determine the side a GPS point is with respect to a line formed by 2 other GPS points?

Tags: navigation, gps, geometry, latitude-longitude, spherical-coordinate

I am moving from point A to B and I have a point C , now I have to decide whether I need to take a left or right or move straight to reach point C. Latitudes and Longitudes of points A, B and C are given.

Comment: "I am moving from point A to point B" seems to be a long term ambition.Where are you at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate bearings A-B and B-C using this [excellent page formulas](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), and compare them